# Enable Autologin for Xvnc/XDMCP?

Tags: gdm, 9.10, login, vnc, xdmcp

**Version: Ubuntu 9.10**

How I do to enable automatic login in Xvnc/XDMCP?

Im in the process of setting up a Xvnc kiosk, which will be a terminal server hosting multiple kiosk machines under separate sessions.

/etc/gdm/custom.conf:

```
[security]
AllowRemoteAutoLogin=true

[xdmcp]
Enable=true
DisplaysPerHost=100
MaxSessions=100

[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=kiosk
```

/etc/xinetd.conf:

```
defaults
{
instances = 20
}
includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

/etc/xinetd.d/xvncserver:

```
service xvncserver
{
socket_type = stream
protocol = tcp
wait = no
user = kiosk
server = /usr/bin/Xvnc4
server_args = -inetd -query localhost -geometry 640x480 -depth 16 -SecurityTypes=none
}
```

What I want, is that when someone connects with a VNC client to the machine, the user who connect should immediately get logged in as the "kiosk" user without being asked for password or something else, just straight into as the user "kiosk".

As it is now, the user just gets a login screen asking for username/password.

Theres no problem running multiple sessions as the same user. I have tested it, all sessions are concurrent and does not affect each other, so theres no need to have a separate kiosk account for each kiosk machine.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned - if you feel this in error, then please flag explaining why and the moderators will reopen it. :)